# Wrong type for value error in Hugo with resource.Minify

Tags: hugo

Running this in /layouts/index.html

```
{{ $styles := resources.Get "css/styles.css" | resources.Minify }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ $styles.Permalink }}" media="screen" />
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 2021/03/29 16:47:57 Failed to render pages: render of "home" failed: "/mnt/c/Users/yashb/quickstart/layouts/index.html:8:51": execute of template failed: template: index.html:8:51: executing "index.html" at : wrong type for value; expected resources.ResourceTransformer; got resource.Resource

My CSS file is located at /public/assets/css/styles.css

Answer (score 1):

I found I had this problem, despite the docs stating that the default value of `assetDir` is `assets` I got upset and set `assetDir` in my `config.toml` file to `assets` and then it worked. So check that that mapping is right.

The css file needs to be in your `/[THEME]/assets/` path.